# Can I make sure that an object value is of type string?

Tags: typescript

I have this type:

```
type DropdownProps<T> = {
  data: T[],
  id: keyof T,
};
```

The problem is that if I now try to use `id` it will have the `any`. I need to make sure that `id` is either type `number` or `string`.

Basically, I want to pass an array of objects and one of the object's keys. That key should return a value of the type `string` or `number`.

I don't want to require the key to be called `id`, but if that's necessary to make it work it would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intersect it with the types you want:

```
type DropdownProps<T> = {
  data: T[],
  id: keyof T & (string | number),
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N9noom)

Comment: That seems to be in the right direction, but how would I use that in this case: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIgTgezAEwQdwHYAVFgM4A8AKgHxQC8UA3gLABQUUyAhsMwFxREDaAugDT1GAS2ScA1hBAIAZlygAyKAAo8wOMIwBzKAB8oGAK4BbAEYQ4ASkEMmwvGAA2zEADlmxiBKmz5StRra9AC+ANz09KCQ8pTwSKiYOEiEVFDcAMogZgiOAHTCwBasCHC8nAAMoVAALABMFVUAREZmFo0VUMEk4XQA9L2MUAB6APwRdPQyhhgAxsDCCBhQAB7EJMpULGz8dg7Obh4QwZxxKOjYuISkltRCUHAQwIZwS1vM3Mj2Ti7unry5wAQABl0BYAMLMPAQZSWKr9KAACXQUDQCEMjmQUAAklBmDMZhA8HgoMAABbQABuzEchmgqlJaIxUHMUF8UWgAU0Wh2Gi0pOAIxu5IeYzowSAA

Comment: @radmacher `data` is an array... You have to access the element first: https://tsplay.dev/w6v9rw

Comment: Right. Could you elaborate on the error? Is there any way to get rid of it or do I need to add a check beforehand that would just return null or something if the value is not of type string?

Comment: @radmacher It's an *array*. You need to get an element and before you can use the key. In my playground above I get the first element, for example.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough in my previous comment. I was asking, how would I make sure that the value is a string. In your Playground, you wrote that the value is currently not guaranteed to be string, but that is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
// to limit T type keys:
type DropdownProps<
  T extends Record<string | number, any>,
  K extends keyof T
> = {
  data: T[],
  myId: K,
};
```

```
// to limit picked keys
type DropdownProps<
  T extends Record<any, any>,
  K extends (keyof T) & (string | number)
> = {
  data: T[],
  myId: K,
};
```